# Realm + RxJava2 how to use equalTo and etc

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2

Now, I am trying to understand how to use Realm with RxJava2. There aren't a lot of information. For example, I have a simple query:

```
CommentObject firstComments =  realmForThisThread.where(CommentObject.class)
                .equalTo(CommentObject.COMMENT,comment).findFirst();
```

How to get firstComment using RxJava2? As I understand asObservable method doesn't work now.

The same questions appear when I want to get RealmResults or set listener only for one model, not all Realm database.

Are there any documents about Realm + RxJava2. I found only RxJava, but it needn't. Before that I worked with Realm without Rx, but now it's important to use this concept

Comment: This is just synchronous query against a Realm instance. There is no reason for Rx to be in it if there are no change listeners (or thread-jumps which are prohibited with managed realmobjects anyways) involved.

Comment: @ EpicPandaForce Does this mean I need to use Rx when I use RealmChangeListener, for example in Recycler adapter?  In the other case I can use clean realm method, without Rx ( for copy, find , save data)?

Comment: You can replace any `RealmChangeListener<T>` with `Flowable<T>`, but a RecyclerAdapter is actually a funny example because Realm already gives `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` which manages the listener added to the results internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read my article on [using Realm with RxJava2 in the Realm Academy](https://academy.realm.io/posts/creating-a-reactive-data-layer-with-realm-and-rxjava2/).

---

Synchronous single-value query makes no sense to be exposed as Observable.

If you want to listen to whether there is `0` or `1` element existing of a RealmObject, then you should use `RealmResults<T>.asFlowable()`.

Using `RealmObject.asFlowable()` is designed for listening to single-element object notifications that provides field change as well.

---

Anyways, using RxJava2 is to allow you to turn this

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<Task> results; // kept as strong reference!
    RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Task>> listener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Task>>() {        
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Task> results) {
            if(results.isLoaded()) {
                // results is always up to date here
                // after a write to Realm from ANY thread!
                updateUi(results);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        results = realm.where(Task.class)
                                .findAllSortedAsync(TaskFields.ID); 
                                  // TaskFields is generated 
                                  // using https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper
        results.addChangeListener(listener);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        results.removeChangeListener(listener);
        results = null;
        realm.close();
    }

    private void updateUi(List<MyObject> objects) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

into this

```
@Singleton
public class TaskRepository  {
    @Inject
    public TaskRepository() {
    }

    // this implementation works on any thread.
    public Flowable<List<Task>> getTasks(Realm realm) {
        if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) { // for looper threads
            return realm.where(Task.class)
                    .findAllSortedAsync(TaskFields.ID)
                    .asFlowable()
                    .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
        } else { // for background threads
            return Flowable.just(realm.where(Task.class).findAllSorted(TaskFields.ID));
        }                    
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TaskRepository taskRepository;

    Realm realm;
    Disposable subscription;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        taskRepository = Injector.get().taskRepository();
        subscription = taskRepository.getTasks(realm).subscribeWith(tasks -> {
            updateUi(tasks);
        });
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        subscription.dispose();
        subscription = null;
        realm.close();
    }

    private void updateUi(List<MyObject> objects) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, nice example. I read the article above, but sometimes it takes more time and more examples to understand how to do better.